# Can't connect to MySQL Database from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I recently set up an OpenShift project with the MySQL 5.5 cartridge.

Now I'm trying to reach this server. The DB name is 'wensput'.

The URL I'm trying to reach the MySQL is:
   `DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://77.78.110.71:3306/Wensput";`
AND
   `DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://IP/wensput";`
WHERE IP = the IP my machine uses to connect to phpAdmin, also the 'Server' (something like: 127.9.203.293:3306

I tried them both with capatilazing and such but nothing seems to work.
Now was my question, do I have the url right? 
Or do I need to use like, the rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin url? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: ****
I first get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception, but: there are no complains about 'CLASSPATH' whatsoever.

Comment: Load the corresponding driver and check

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not your MySQL server. There are no complaints about classpath, as JDBC drivers are loaded dynamically. You currently don't have the JDBC driver on your classpath.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the JDBC driver installed or are not importing it correctly. Take a look at this tutorial for detailed instructions:
[Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database/2840358#2840358)

Comment: Although this answer has been downvoted, it was true, I didnt have the jdbc in my WEB-INF/lib but in 'external jars'. Sadly enough, now I can't connect to my username/pass are incorrect :/